# Doctrine – how to set up one-to-one relationship between two entities

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I have two tables: Users and Contacts

> Users
>
> - id
> - username
>
> Contacts
>
> - id
> - user_id
> - email
>     (I have simplified the structure)

Now, how to setup doctrine entities properly?

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
class User extends BaseEntity {

    /**
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue
     * @Column(type="bigint")
     */
     protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=true)
     */
    protected $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Contact")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="user_id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     **/
    protected $contact;
}
```

Contact entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="contacts")
 */
class Contact extends BaseEntity {

    /**
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue
     * @Column(type="bigint")
     */
     protected $id;

    /**
     * @var User
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $email;
}
```

The thing is that I'm not sure whether the entity relationship is set properly.

1. I don't know how to set if `User` is deleted then delete `Contact` but not the other way.
2. If I create `$user = new User()` and then `$contact = new Contact()` how to join them? `$user->contact = $contact`? Will it after `persist()` and `flush()` fill `user_id` correctly and insert data into both tables?
3. I'm getting error `A new entity was found through the relationship '...\User#contact' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: ...\Contact@0000000015f3aa5e000000012cd799f5. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement '...\Contact#__toString()' to get a clue.` I'm stuck on this one which I think is related to my problem #1 and therefore I can't test #2.

I have been browsing docs for hours now but I got stuck and I didn't find any real example that would guide me... Can anyone help me by showing me proper configuration of these entities' relationship?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to cascade a user deletion so its contact also gets deleted, in the `Contact` entity add `onDelete="CASCADE"` to the
`JoinColumn` annotation of the `$user` property (this will only delete a contact if its user is deleted)

```
/**
 * @var User
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
private $user;
```

If you persist the contact before adding it to the user you should not get any error. If you want to add a new contact by directly assigning the new un-persisted contact to a user,
then you'll need to add `cascade={"persist", "remove"}` to your `User` entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Contact",cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
 **/
protected $contact;
```

Comment: Ok thank you, that sounds good. Although, I tried setting `cascade={"persist", "remove"})` and when I do `$user = new User()` `$contact = new Contact()` `$user->contact = $contact` `$entityManager->persist($user)` `$entityManager->flush()` User gets created but not Contact. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If I manually `persist($contact)` it works. Do I have to do it or can I somehow include it through `@ORM` annotations?

Comment: @simPod adding `cascade={"persist", "remove"})` to the `$contact` property of your `User` entity should allow you to add an un-persisted contact to a `User`. do you have any other mappings in `User` that might be causing the problem?