# Symfony Doctrine Delete only one site in one to one relationship

Tags: symfony, doctrine, sql-delete, one-to-one

I have an entity **Image** related (oneToOne) to the entity **Airline**. Images can be replaced or deleted but airlines should still be kept after the images has been deleted.

How do I set this up in my Entity class? Right now I have:

**Airline entity**

```
    /**
* @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Image", inversedBy="airline")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="image_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
*/
private $image;
```

**Image entity**

```
 /**
   * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Airline", inversedBy="image", orphanRemoval=true)
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="airline_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
  */
  private $airline;
```

But I get an ForeignKeyConstraintViolation Exception because it tries to delete the airline entity, too. I'm sure I have to set the *onDelete* differently or the *orphanRemoval* is misplaced_?

I already played around with it but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Have a look at this question. Maybe the answer gets you ahead https://stackoverflow.com/a/27670974/5947371

Comment: hmm it did not exactly help me! So, I understand that I can add two parameters in the cascade or Delete part, but I don't know which ones would apply on my side.. sorry, could you help me further? @Fabian

Comment: Do you delete images using Doctrine ORM? (`$em->delete($image)`)